# How to show custom XML tags instead of string tag

Tags: c#, web-services, tags, restful-url

I have a RESTFUL API service that returns the City, State, Zip, etc. of a location with a unique id number. In my function that gets the data I am returning an Array called "List". The array results in `<string>Kansas City</string>` for an example.

How can I have customer tags like `<City>Kansas City</City> <State>MO</State>.`?

A snippet of my code in the function is:

```
string [] List = new string [7];
            List[0]= City;
            List[1]= County;
            List[2]= State;
            List[3]=Postal;
            List[4]=isDefaultLocation;
            List[5]=locationId;
            List[6]=AtlasKey;

            return List;
```

The results are returned in XML format using example.com/locations/id/10000

Comment: Well how are you returning the data from your API?

Comment: You need to implement a class that encapsulates all the data you want to send over the wire, and then use either DataContract or XmlSerializer to emit the desired XML output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own class, for example:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization; // XML serialization requires this namespace
using System.IO;

[XmlRootAttribute("Info")]
public class Info
{
    // static constructor will create serializer instance
    static Info()
    {
        Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Info));
    }        

    // here write constructor based on array of strings

    // this method will serialize current object to stream
    public void SerializeToXml(Stream stream)
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
    }

    // this static method will deserialize object from stream
    public static Info DeserializeFromXml(Stream stream)
    {
        return Serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Info;
    }

    [XmlElement("City")] // use XmlElement, not XmlAttribute
    public string City
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // here you can add your other fields like above

    [XmlIgnore] // we want to be sure that this field won't be serialized
    private static XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```